# Creating a seamless vector dataset from raster with gdal, R or Python

Tags: python, gdal, r, vectorization, scikit-image

I'm trying to create a seamless vector dataset from an integer raster. "Seamless" as in: not gaps between features and no overlapping features.

The tools `gdal_polygonize`, `pkpolygonize`, `terra::as.polygons` (in R) all do pretty much exactly that, but they have a major flaw: They trace the raster cells *precisely*, resulting in overly complex features as soon as they include diagonals, curves etc.

[image: Original raster (middle), vector data with gdal_polygonize]

Cleaning these features in a post processing step (eg. `ogr2ogr -simplify` leads to topological errors (overlaps and gaps).

I'm very surprised that solving this turns out to be so hard. I imagine that this is a common problem in GIS workflows, e.g. the [CORINE Landcover dataset](https://sdi.eea.europa.eu/catalogue/srv/api/records/53ef1493-e7a1-4216-b043-87a7c2a5a68d) is based on satellite imagery, but they also produce a vector data product with the attributes I desire: no gaps, no overlaps and simplified. *How do they generate this vector data?* Regrettably, I could not find information on this.

This answer [Extract polygons from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26891092/4139249) talks about using `scikit-image` for this. Would this be the way to go?

I'm looking for ways to solve this using python, R or the command line. The output should be something [`gdal` compatible](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html), preferably *.gpkg* or *.shp*.

The data I'm using can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zUqVMknJlMLsb_coc8WJiuL-wy781RHS/view?usp=sharing) (4kb):

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423272/smoothing-out-lines-created-by-raster-layers/423284#423284

Comment: @BERA: These are are all feature-by-feature approaches where simplification results in overlapping polygons and gaps between polygons. I'm looking for somethings that guarantees that the resulting data set does not have gaps or overlaps, but is still simple.

Comment: You can fix the gaps. For example create a big rectangular poygon covering your entire data set. Difference this and your converted to get small polygons where there are holes. Select these and [Eliminate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336131/eliminate-sliver-polygons-qgis-3) them

Comment: you need a simplification algorithm that keeps topology intact, try mapshaper

Comment: There *must* be a way to create seamless polygons from the get-go. On [twitter](https://twitter.com/mdsumner/status/1494121617147842560), @mdsumner suggested using `gdal_contour`,  but this approach is for continuous variables and cannot handle skipping classes. My data is **huge** and I really don't want to create topological errors in the first place.

Comment: @bugmenot123: Thanks for the tip: I will try this and report how it goes.

Comment: Being quite familiar with the production process of the corine landcover dataset, it is unfortunately not as easy as you think, and there is no one-liner solution ;)

Comment: oh thats a bummer..  I've scanned through the [CLC Documentation](https://land.copernicus.eu/user-corner/technical-library) and did not find specifics about their approach. Mind sharing your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to your question. Usually simplification and generalization of data makes the most sense. You can use positive and negative buffer, data union/intersection etc, depending on the needs.

There are several approaches to simplify the data, a good overview you can find in [Generalization of spatial data: Principles and selected algorithms](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-63818-0_5)

A very simple approach could be:

```r
r <- terra::rast("/home/sapi/Downloads/sample.tif")
terra::plot(r)
```

[image]

Let's take only one layer:

```r
p <- terra::as.polygons(r)
terra::plot(p[2])
```

[image]

```r
p[2] |>
  terra::buffer(width = 3) |>
  terra::simplifyGeom(tolerance = 1) |>
  terra::union() |>
  terra::buffer(width = -3) |>  
  terra::fillHoles() |>
  terra::plot()
```

[image]

But in practice, it depends what do you expect from your output data. What will be purpose on it? What's the desired scale? Shall be the less important features removed prior to generalization? Which one are the "less important"?

Let's remove the polygons with small area first:

```r
p[2] |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "POLYGON") |>
  dplyr::mutate(area = as.numeric(sf::st_area(geometry))) |>
  subset(area >= 100) |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 3) |>
  sf::st_simplify() |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = -3) |>
  subset(select = "area") |>
  terra::vect() |>
  terra::fillHoles() |>
  terra::plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There is [smoothr](https://strimas.com/smoothr/index.html) package for R as well.

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>